# First element disappearing using Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner learning about data structures and Abstract Data Types in C. I am creating a simple linked-list implementation, but when I try to print the list, I seem to lose the first element. The Node type just consists of an integer and a pointer to itself.

My main file

```
  int main()
  {
     Node * List=createList();

     int testData[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

     for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
     {
       addFront(List,testData[i]);
       printList(List);
       printf("\n");
     }

  }
```

addToFront and its supporting initNode are defined thusly:

```
 void addFront(Node * List, int value)
 {
    Node * toAdd = initNode(value);

    toAdd-> next = List->next;

    List->next = toAdd;
 }



 Node * initNode(int val)
 {
    Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode -> value = val;
    newNode-> next = NULL;

    return newNode;
 }
```

EDIT: As per request, printList() is:

```
  void printList(Node * List)
  {
     Node * original = List->next;

     while (List->next != NULL)
     { 
        printf("%d\n",List->value);
        List = List ->next;
     }

     List = original;
  }
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show `printList()` as well?  Adding looks ok as long as the initial node (`List` in `main()`) isn't supposed to hold part of the actual data.

Comment: I just want to ask you, do you want add a new node in the front or in the back of the list ?

Comment: I add a new node to the front of the list. @Dmitri when I initialize the list, I allocate memory for a node and assign it to the head pointer but i don't store anything.

Comment: To get a full answer, you should post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Problem is in `printList()`...

Comment: @pingOfDoom I believe I fixed my answer for you. Pass in a pointer to the Node pointer, then you can modify it properly.

Comment: im getting incompatability errors. *List dereferences it and makes it a Node and it doesn't like that im passing that to a Node pointer

Comment: Again, this call `List = original;` is useless.

Comment: Doesn't that "reset" where the List pointer points to back to the beginning of the list?

Comment: It does, but the change to `List` never got propagated upwards to the caller, so no need to reset it. `List` along with it's value goes away the moment the function is exited. C is pass by value.

Comment: @pingOfDoom you don't need to "reset" `List` because the `List` from the function arguments is a separate variable local to the function, not the same as the one from `main()`.

Comment: And the next time, you debug this yourself using a debugger, don't you? ;-)

Comment: Yes of course. Its just that I'm not very adept with those kinds of tools, like gdb or valgrind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first node is not used for data but only to point to the rest of the list, most of your code looks ok.  The problem is that you're not printing all the nodes in your list.

Inside `printList()`, you don't need `original` since `List` from the function arguments is local anyway... and you need to break the loop when the node you're looking at is `NULL` instead of when its `next` node is `NULL` (since the `while` test happens before the loop body).

Here's a shortened and corrected version, which also updates the `List` pointer inside the while condition instead of before the loop and in the loop body.

```
void printList(Node * List)
{
   while ((List = List->next) != NULL)
   { 
      printf("%d\n",List->value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Here I thought it was an issue with my adding function when it turned out to be a problem with what I used to print.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding to the front, yet you are setting the next element in `toAdd` to `List->next`. You are skipping the first element.

Furthermore, you are setting `List->next` to `toAdd` afterwards.

What you want to do is this:

```
void addFront(Node** List, int value)
{
    Node * toAdd = initNode(value);
    toAdd->next = *List;
    *List = toAdd;
}
```

Pass in a pointer to the Node pointer, that allows you to modify the head from within the function.

As per alk's comment, call it this way now: `addFront(&List,testData[i]);`

Comment: but then doesn't that just make toAdd-> next = toAdd? When I initialize the list, i allocate some memory for the head. this doesn't seem correct to me since the head should only point to the first element, but i get warnings otherwise

Comment: This statement `List = toAdd;`  is useless.

Comment: @alk How is it useless? Granted, this is not how I would implement it normally, I would rather return a new list than overwrite List (ie return toAdd)

Comment: Doing `List = toAdd;` just changes the variable `List` local to `addFront()` then the function exits. You could just delete `List = toAdd;`.

Comment: However in doing any of that, now nothing prints out.

Comment: And this last change isn't valid as it assigns a `Node*` to a `Node`, to which `*List` evaluates.

Comment: I think `List` is just a dummy node and the real list begins at `List->next`... in which case his original `addFront()` looks ok.

Comment: @alk Yeah fixed that.

Comment: And finally it might be worth mentioning that calling `addFront()` now needs to be done differently: `addFront(&List,testData[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's problem in your print list function.you should need to print until current node is not equal to null. i.e in Java I use while loop ..

While (curnode!=null)
*Remember.next not used here because when you use it then your One element will be skip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).